# wants SUMIFS formula help for a comlex query

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I have attached summary sheet and data sheet. Summary is where I want the formula and INCdata is the data sheet where the raw data is available.

I need a formula to sum the column J in the summary sheet for the conditions below:

1) dates in column A are falls in a calendar month

2) when column C is not equal to column D

3) should also exclude column J values when column C has values like "SUPPLIER" and "OTHER" in them.

[Summary sheet that needs the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laMOd.png)

The formula I am using in the cell AT116 right now is **=SUMIFS(INCdata!$J:$J,INCdata!$A:$A,">="&$B115,INCdata!$A:$A,"<"&$B116,INCdata!$P:$P,"1")**

[INCdata - data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLxtf.png)

I have a column P (sheet name:**INCdata**) where I am checking condition 2 and 3 given above using this formula in the cell P5766 for every row (**=IF($C5766="SUPPLIER",0,IF($C5766="OTHER",0,IF($C5766=$D5766,0,1)))**), based on which the formula in the summary sheets yields the results for sum of J. But if there is a way to avoid using a separate formula here and include this criteria in the summary sheet formula, it would be ideal.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Did you try to solve your problem? We encourage people to try something, before posting. Have a look at these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @Daemon Trust me I have tried so many different ways to solve this and I have solved the problem but in a way different from ideal. I wanted to know if fresh set of eyes can come up with a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Vino try this `=SUMIFS(J:J,D:D,E4,E:E,D4)` this will do the first part.

This would zero anything with Supplier or Other in cell C and do the above. `=IF(OR(C4="Supplier",C4="Other"),0,SUMIFS(J:J,B:B,C4,C:C,B4))`

I am not to sure what you have done with the dates so cant try and help there.

Hope this helps. Any questions let me know.

Comment: Hi I have added more details to the initial query and I hope it makes sense. Let me know if I am missing any information.

Comment: Hello Vino, the only way i can think of doing it at the moment is in three stages.  

The formula you have AT on INCData change to this: = `=IF(OR(C2="Suppler",C2="Other",C2=D2),0,L2)`

Then in the next column add this formula `=YEAR(A2)&MONTH(A2)`

Then on summary sheet add this formula `=SUMIF(Sheet2!P:P,YEAR(Sheet1!B2)&MONTH(Sheet1!B2),Sheet2!O:O)`
Sheet 2 is your Data Sheet and Sheet 1 is your Summary Sheet.  

This gives you your desired outcome but in more formulas than i would have liked.  If you use it, let me know and i will update the answer, so you can mark it and close it.